# Print each row of data.frame on separate page and each column on new line

Tags: r, latex, tidyverse, knitr, stringr

I want to print each row of a `data.frame`  or `tibble` on separate page and string separated with  `\n` on next line. Any hint.

```
library(tidyverse)
tb1 <-
  tibble(
    A = c("A1", "A2", "A3")
  , B = c("B1", "B2", "B3")
  , C = c("C1", "C2", "C3")
  )

tb2 <-
  tb1 %>% 
  mutate(Total = paste(A, B, C, sep = " \n ")) %>% 
  select(Total)

tb2

library(kableExtra)

kbl(x = tb2, format = "latex")
```

Comment: Yes, I want print the output with `knitr` in `pdf` format

Comment: I am using `.Rnw`

Comment: Any solution @RonakShah

Comment: Even R Markdown is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Markdown chunk works for me -

````
```
---
title: "temp"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
tb2 <- structure(list(Total = c("A1 \n B1 \n C1", "A2 \n B2 \n C2", 
"A3 \n B3 \n C3")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

for(i in seq(nrow(tb2))) {
  cat(gsub('\n', ' \n ', tb2$Total[i]))
  cat("\n\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
}
```
````